# Create Outlook Form or Template with required fields in body and an Approval button

Tags: forms, templates, outlook

I'm tasked with creating an Outlook form that will be used to communicate rate changes to our customers, and ask for their approval. The body of the email must have some fields that are required by the sender, such as customer name, and new rate. And the email must have an approval button or similar from the recipient. Its a relatively basic workflow

As I'm researching Outlook forms, I discovered this might be better suited for Outlook templates instead. But I'm new to this, and I'm not sure the difference between the two.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Custom Outlook forms should be displayed on both sides of communication if you really want them working correctly. It is very inconvenient, so this feature is not really used nowadays.

Instead, you may consider using the [MailItem.VotingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingoptions) property which returns or sets a string specifying a delimited string containing the voting options for the mail message. This property uses the character specified in the value name, `sList`, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple voting options. As a result the recipient will see possible options to choose on the UI.

When the response comes back you may check the [MailItem.VotingResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingresponse) property which returns or sets a string specifying the voting response for the mail message. This property is usually set to one of the delimited values returned by the `VotingOptions` property on a reply to the original message.

And the third solution is to develop a COM add-in which can handle custom data and provide a convenient UI for voting, for example, a custom form region can be developed for that. Again, this solution, like custom Outlook forms, requires installing the software on both sides of communication.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

What’s most important is requiring certain fields to be populated by the sender before delivering the email. I tried using Outlook forms. I was able to create the fields, and make them required, but can’t figure out how to insert them into the body of the email

Comment: You can't actually. The world is not perfect.